# Based on a number, list out x number of a letter.

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for an array formula to list out x number y's, where is x an integer input that is dynamic.

For example, if the number 10 is inputted. I want an array of cells to show y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y

If 4 is inputted then an array of y,y,y,y

Comment: Is this all in once cell? (see getwebb's answer if so).  Or do you want the array to be in a column?

Comment: No. I'd like to have an array in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the desired array size in A1, place this formula in B1 and fill down:

```
=IF(ROW(B1)-ROW($B$1)<$A$1,"y","")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **rept** function

```
=rept("y,",A1)
```

Where A1 contains your input number